# some javascript code doesn't working - if() sentence in event-handler 'onclick'

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
var head = document.getElementById('head');
var navMain = document.getElementById('navMain');
var navLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('navLink');
var floatEnder_1 = document.getElementById('floatEnder_1');
var iMainContents = document.querySelector('iframe#iMainContents');


// function change class of #head    
    function changeHeadClass(from, to) {
    if(head.className === from) {head.className = to;}
};

// event : click #navMain
    navMain.onclick = function(){
        changeHeadClass('head','head_small');
        floatEnder_1.style.display = 'none';

        if(iMainContents.style.display == 'none') {
           iMainContents.style.display = 'initial'; 
           };
    }
```

Please watch above codes. I'm trying to do unobtrusive js coding, but it is more difficult than insert js event code in html.

When you see above, most of codes are works fine. but only one sentence, `if(iMain...)` isn't working. I read 'javascript definition guide 5th' and console report of browsers, but can't find the reason of the problem...

**http://jsfiddle.net/40ee6ady/**

I wrote my codes above there.

Comment: "It works a little bit" either code works or it doesn't. Please explain your problem better. What is the code supposed to do and what does it do? "It doesn't work" is not a problem description.

Comment: sorry for that uncertain explanation. little bit means, it works on firefox(not on IE) with console error message : navMain is null.

Comment: Have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element, that might be the issue.

Comment: no, I think that... sequence of reading js code is not the reason. because put in js code in the bottom of the html code. right above the </body>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `iMainContents.offsetParent === null` or `window.getComputedStyle(element)` for this,

```
if(iMainContents.offsetParent === null) {
    iMainContents.style.display = 'initial';
}
```

Or

```
if(window.getComputedStyle(iMainContents).display == 'none') {
    iMainContents.style.display = 'initial';
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/40ee6ady/1/)

[First one is much more better that the second option in performance manner](http://jsperf.com/check-hidden)

Comment: Future visitors will benefit if you explain why.

Answer (score 0):

No one knows the reason of the problem.

So I made a detour using jquery'show()' function.

below is the code.

```
$(iMainContents).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you already resolve this problem.

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        var head = document.getElementById('head');
        var navMain = document.getElementById('navMain');
        var iMainContents = document.querySelector('iframe#iMainContents');

        function changeHeadClass(from, to) {
            if(head.className === from) {
                head.className = to;
            }
        };

        navMain.onclick = function(){
            changeHeadClass('head','head_small');
            if(iMainContents.style.display === '') {
                iMainContents.style.display = 'initial';
            };
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

change the code to

```
   if(iMainContents.style.display == '') {
          iMainContents.style.display = 'initial'; 
   };
```

because `display =none` will show '' in `style.display`.

Comment: it doesn't work. I think JS'engine read that sentence 'display:none' as attribute 'display' and property of 'display' as string 'none'. not ''.